# Automapper mapping validation during application startup in .net core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

When I was using Automapper v6 (I'm using .net core), I had this command to validate configuration :

```
   configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

But now, after moving to the latest version, I don't have this since my config is exactly ([docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core)):

```
   private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AppSettingsMappingProfile));    //marker type    
        }
```

However, I still want to validate all mappings at startup .

The docs says that I need to do this :

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
  cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>());

configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

But I don't have it since I'm using profiles with this command :

```
 services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AppSettingsMappingProfile));
```

**Question**:

How can I still make AutoMapper scan for validation at startup?

Comment: "bootstrap" is not a term used in the SWE world - mostly because it _originally_ refers to the computer boot phase (the term "computer boot" comes from "to pull yourself up by one's bootstraps"), and also because people will think you're talking about Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: edited..........(although i did not put bootstrap css tag....).

Comment: `AssertConfigurationIsValid` is designed to be only used at dev time. You should have an `#if DEBUG` or smth similar.

Comment: `ConfigureStartupServices` is not a standard `class Startup` / `IStartup` method name. How is it being called?

Comment: @Dai (ConfigureServices calls it, sorry for the wrong copy paste. Edited). Thanks. I really think the docs there needs a re-cap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the source code for [AddAutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/src/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs), you will see that it registers `IConfigurationProvider` as singleton. This means you can safely have it in your Configure method and do the validation there:

```
public void Configure(IConfigurationProvider pr)
{
    pr.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Maxim. I didnt want to call `BuildServiceProvider` inside ConfigureSErvices as it will create a new container. This epxplain what Lucene said in his comment. I just didn't know where to inject it

Comment: .net 6 does not use a Configure method (in Startup.cs), only program.cs which does not take constructor injection. Where would you put this in a .net 6 project?

Comment: @ngless 
var app = builder.Build();
var mapper = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IMapper>();
mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

Answer (score 2):

Following these steps should work:

1. Add [AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/) NuGet
   package
2. `services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(...))` within
   `ConfigureServices(...)`.
3. Add `IMapper mapper` as parameter to `Configure(...)` method
4. `mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` within
   `Configure(...)`

Example (omitting namespace inclusion)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IMapper mapper)
{
    mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```